# Jstl not working on Spring 5

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, model, attributes, jstl

I created a simple Spring MVC example, and I am having problems translating model attributes on the jsp file. Here is the code:

**public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.package.path"})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
  resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
  resolver.setExposePathVariables(true);
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  return resolver;
}
}
```

**HomeController**

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String userForm(Locale locale, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("users", "test");
    return "hometest";
}
```

**hometest.jsp**

```
<!doctype html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<c:out value="${users}"></c:out>
```

When I run the application, it works fine, the home.jsp file opens normally but it just displays

```
${users}
```

instead of

```
test
```

If I comment the InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() method out, the application doesn't run, it cannot find any pages to display, so it means that this method is being executed... but why the model attribute is not being passed to the jsp file?

Comment: Which is the exact spring version that you using for this.
I tried with 5.0.3.RELEASE and it works fine for me.